# Castle Windsor Interception on registered Classes instead of Components

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am just learning Castle Windsor and was trying to use AOP to solve a few issues and wanted to use the Interception feature to accomplish this.

I have figured out how to get it to work with single components by doing the following.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IInterceptor>()
                .ImplementedBy<BankServiceLogger>()
                .Named("BankServiceInteceptor"));

            container.Register(Component.For<IBankService>()
                .ImplementedBy<BankService>()
                .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForKey("BankServiceInteceptor")).Anywhere
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

My issue is when registering classes such as controllers as I have done here

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IController>()                
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

There doesn't appear to be an Interceptors use on this.

Is there a way to do interception when registering multiple classes or do I need to register each component individually to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't AOP dead and forgotten yet?

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, Castle AOP died about 5 years ago, however this question is about the AOP functionality in Castle Windsor which internally uses the AOP functionality offered by Castle DynamicProxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Configure` method on the `BasedOnDescriptor` provides this ability (as well as the ability to configure many other things), however I just realised because `Configure` is designed to take an `Action<ComponentRegistration>` you can't call the `Anywhere` property on the `InterceptorGroup` so the interceptors don't get applied to the component registration. Below is the best workaround I could work out.

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyInterceptor>());
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IController>().WithService.FromInterface()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    //.Configure(c => c.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyInterceptor>()).Anywhere)
    .Configure(delegate(ComponentRegistration c) { var x = c.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyInterceptor>()).Anywhere; })
);
```